# Is it possible in mysql to execute statement without using prepared

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have created the following stored procedure in MySQL 8.0 for dropping functions. I am calling this stored procedure to drop any function:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `_CCC_DBObject_DropFunctionIfExists`; 
$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `_CCC_DBObject_DropFunctionIfExists`(
    FunctionName VarChar(128)
)
BEGIN
    Declare strSQL VarChar(6000);
    SET strSQL = 'DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `<FunctionName>`';
    SET strSQL = Replace(strSQL, '<FunctionName>', FunctionName);
    SET @SQLString = strSQL;
    PREPARE sqlToRun FROM @SQLString; 
        EXECUTE sqlToRun;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

However, when I try to call this stored procedure using the following statement:

```
CALL `cccreportsunittest`.`_CCC_DBObject_DropFunctionIfExists`('CalculateSquare');
```

I receive the error message:

> Error Code: 1295. This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet.

I've even tried a few different things to run a direct statement in the editor, so I can use it in SP afterward, but I'm not able to execute it.

```
SET @strSQL = 'DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS CalculateSquare';
PREPARE stmt FROM @strSQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I understand that prepared statements are not supported for functions in MySQL. Is there any other way I can achieve the same functionality without using the PREPARE statement?

I have similar stored procedures for dropping views, tables, and columns in my project, and they work fine. However, I am facing this issue specifically with functions.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: [SQL Syntax Permitted in Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html#prepared-statements-permitted). The statements not mentioned in this list cannot be executed dynamically.

Comment: If the list of function names which may be used/deleted in your code then you may use CASE statement with according static queries: `CASE FunctionName WHEN 'fn1' THEN DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn1; WHEN 'fn2' THEN DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn2; WHEN ... END;`

Comment: @Akina , as per my project requirements, I need to create a stored procedure and use it. Additionally, I don't have a specific function name since it will keep on adding, so I'm unable to write it statically as you mentioned in the switch case.

Comment: Then make a big report or look if there is one alteadyy but as long myssql doesn't support it you need to write an extension

Comment: Or change the project requirements as it is not possible to comply with those. The simplest solution would be to write an external script that dynamically assembles the sql statement and executes it.